# Изменение поля description в gitweb

Tags: windows, git

В *gitweb* в поле *description* проекта следующее описание:

```
Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository.
```

И я хочу изменить это описание проекта. В своём локальном репозитории я изменила файл *.git\description*, но как передать эти изменения на удалённый репозиторий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев, никак. Файл `.git\description` автоматически не синхронизируется с удалённым репозиторием.

На сервере создаётся обычно так называемый *bare* (пустой, не содержащий рабочей копии) репозиторий.
В *gitweb*  колонкa `|Project|` выглядит в этом случае, например так: `myproject.git`.

Изменить  описание проекта можно прямо на сервере, где лежит удалённый репозиторий, отредактировав первую строчку файла: `/repos_root_path/myproject.git/description`.

---

> gitweb is not interested in a working area, and is best suited to showing "bare" repositories

Gitweb первоночально создавался для *bare* репозиториев и файл `description` используется только в нём, больше нигде. Как следствие, синхронизация этого файла не была предусмотрена.

В актуальной версии *gitweb* также работает с *non-bare* репозиториями, то есть содержащими рабочие копии.
Колонкa `|Project|` в *gitweb*  будет выглядеть тогда,  например так: `myproject/.git` (со слешем).

В этом случае, воспользуйтесь уже опубликованным рабочим решением в ответе от @NickVolynkin.
Можно также ознакомиться [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991406/updating-description-of-project-in-bare-repository) и перейти в принятом ответе по ссылке для аналогичного решения.

Подробности в [документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb).

Answer (score 1):

Файлы в `.git` нельзя версионировать.

Переместите файл в корневую директорию проекта. Сделайте симлинк в каждом репозитории, где используется gitweb:

```
mv .git/description .
ln -s ../description .git/description

# проверим, что симлинк работает:
cat .git/description
```

Если ОС не позволяет делать симлинки, добавьте post-receive hook, копирующий `description` в `.git/description`.

Comment: Будет ли так  файл description в  удалённом репозитории на сервере изменён? Я прямо там изменял и gitweb отображает правильно.

Comment: @simpleCode будет, когда вы 1) на сервере сделаете симлинк и 2) запушите туда коммит, в котором добавили файл description.

Comment: Попробовал, не работает. Сделал свежего клона и .git/description уже приходит со стандартной строкой "Unknown ...", а не то, что лежит на сервере и отображается в gitweb. В любом случае линк поправте - ln -s ../description .git/description`.

Comment: @simpleCode конечно в свежем клоне будет `.git/description` стандартный — этот файл же не версионируется. Повторю: «сделайте симлинк в каждом репозитории». Это значит, что дефолтный `descriptinon` нужно удалить и вместо него сделать симлинк.

Comment: @simpleCode про симлинк действительно ошибка была, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @simpleCode смысл этого трюка в том, что когда вы вручную один раз сделаете симлинк, description станет версионируемым. Но одно ручное действие всё равно придётся делать в каждом репозитории.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если есть минутка загляни https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat